# Disambiguating the [mocha] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mocha) tag has at least two meanings:

- [With JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mocha+javascript): [Mocha, the JavaScript test framework](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/)
- [With Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mocha+ruby~): [Mocha, the Ruby mocking library](http://rubygems.org/gems/mocha)

What should they be disambiguated to? Are there other uses of the tag?

At 127 questions tagged [mocha][ruby] or [mocha][ruby-on-rails], compared to 351 questions tagged [mocha][javascript] or [mocha][node.js], the JS use has a strong majority. It may nonetheless be a good idea to rename that too to avoid confusion.

(I know nothing about either Mocha, I just noticed the ambiguity when reviewing a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/268041) to the tag wiki.)

Current [mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mocha) tag definition is the first.

> Mocha is a feature-rich JavaScript test framework running on Node.js
>   and the browser.

Comment: We need a `mocha-latte`  tag?

Comment: For many years *Mocha* referred to the original Java decompiler, now largely forgotten.

Comment: I haven't yet figured out a way to create disambiguation tags, but in this case, I hope it will be possible.

Comment: @AndersonGreen I don't understand your question. Do you mean how we can indicate that this tag is ambiguous? I've done that by posting on meta. The tag needs to be split; I don't know either subject, nor whether there are yet other topics that use the same tag name, which is why I'm calling for experts to pick names and go retag.

Comment: [mocha-test-framework] and [mocha-mocking-lib]?

Answer (score 5):

Given that the Javascript frameworks' own domain is `mochajs.org`, I think it would be appropriate to introduce a `mocha.js` or `mochajs` tag, and move all the javascript-related usages of [mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mocha) to it (those which are also tagged with [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), etc.).

We could then refocus `mocha` tag for the ruby-related usages.

Idk how to do this en-masse, though. Would it require moderator intervention?

Comment: The Debian way is that none get the tag. So ruby's should be ruby-mocha.

Comment: Yeah, [ruby-mocha] would be the way to go, then we rename [mocha] to [mochajs] or some such. Disambiguation is critical here, tho

Comment: SOCVR chipped in on the disambiguation so all the Ruby stuff lives in [tag:ruby-mocha] now. Tag is renamed