# How should Meta Stack Overflow proposals be brought to moderators' attention?

Tags: support, meta, moderation

This may seem like a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266782/on-meta-how-do-you-get-attention-for-questions-without-an-answer) at first glance, but it isn't. There are a few proposed changes (like retag-requests) that have been around for quite some time and despite community approval, they don't seem to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) or [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Please don't see this as me criticizing the moderators. I know that they have a very busy job and probably just didn't stumble upon these questions yet. However, my question is: How can the average user bring proposals like those to the moderators' attention? I reckon to flag them for their intervention is not what I should be doing and you can't open bounties on Meta.

Here are some examples:

- <s>[Disambiguating the [mocha] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272096/7910454)</s>
- [Disentangle the [yarn]!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354583/7910454)
- <s>[Let's rename [babel], because people constantly use it instead of [babeljs]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310149/lets-rename-babel-because-people-constantly-use-it-instead-of-babeljs)</s>
- <s>[Replace [jest] tag with something more specific](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399571/replace-jest-tag-with-something-more-specific)</s>
- [Can we rename [redux] and [redux-framework] into [redux-js] and [redux-wordpress] tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323939/can-we-rename-redux-and-redux-framework-into-redux-js-and-redux-wordpress)
- [Burninate [next]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/273028/7910454)
- [Axe the [device]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298565/7910454)

Comment: We have a formalized process (complete with its own chatroom) for tag change requests, but it is in limbo with Bhargav Rao on leave and no other mod having taken up the mantle.

Comment: @TylerH That's very interesting. Is this documented somewhere? If not: Can you maybe write up a quick answer detailing the process?

Comment: I would largely just be duplicating [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) from the [Official Meta FAQ list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow). (Note, I didn't vote to close as a dupe of those as you seem to be asking about a slightly more broad subject than *just* re-tag or tag clean-up requests).

Comment: @TylerH Those two are burnination related and the FAQ doesn't include a question about synonym/retag-requests, does it? Maybe I just didn't see it tho.

Comment: The process covers other general processes about tags: for example one of the prerequisite steps before actually burninating a tag is tag cleanup, which usually necessitates retagging to some degree. See also [I've discovered a bad tag, and am unsure what to do about it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388319/ive-discovered-a-bad-tag-and-am-unsure-what-to-do-about-it), and [Is there guidance on tag disambiguation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373035/is-there-guidance-on-tag-disambiguation) for more reading.

Comment: @TylerH Again those are good sources but they aren't really answering the question, provide a link to the chatroom or describe a process that hasn't been followed. If you take the [yarn]-proposal for example. I have cleaned up the entire tag and continue to do so every day with new questions. However, at some point, the renaming has to take place. So thanks for the effort but those posts are unfortunately not really helpful.

Comment: You used to be able to bounty them.

Comment: @TravisJ Really? How did that work without reputation changes?

Comment: There used to be rep on meta until the great "split" where they ruined meta, overworked the CM's, and kicked off an epic downward spiral of disconnect across the exchanges.

Comment: @TravisJ Sounds like the old times where [fun](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309105/what-kind-of-computer-is-being-used-in-workin-on-ur-problemz) was allowed and [unicorns roamed the land](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228048/why-do-unicorn-related-posts-have-so-many-upvotes) ^^

Comment: As @TylerH mentions, I've been away from October, [and I don't plan to get back to handling tag related requests any time soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341133/311398). But given that you asked about those two ... 1. Falls into [this category](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373599/4099593), which I had planned to handle starting this summer (now I won't). 2. That's something for which I need Shog9, who doesn't work with SE anymore, and it's jus not [yarn]; [babel], [mongoose], [elixir] are the ones that come to my mind.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We've seen them. You get our attention by putting the appropriate tag(s) on the posts. These are my watched and ignored tags on Meta:

[image: ]]

I abuse the "watched tags" feature to highlight posts asking for retags, and I abuse the "ignored tags" feature to gray out posts where the action has already been completed.

However, there's a big gap between *seeing* these and having the time to *action them*. We currently live in that gap.

I try very hard whenever I get a chance to carry out the requests that are obviously reasonable (in my judgment) and that can be quickly implemented by a moderator with a couple of button clicks. These are things like tag renames, synonym requests, etc.

However, for the requests that require substantial amounts of clean-up effort, and therefore involvement of the larger community, there just hasn't been the time, opportunity, or motivation recently.

Rest assured that your requests are not being ignored, and will not be forgotten. Once "burnination" efforts resume, we'll pick up with the highest-scoring requests, so use your votes to indicate consensus.

Comment: Is there a reason you are living in that gap? Sincere question as I'm somewhat dumbfounded by this answer, to be honest.

Comment: Lots of things going on right now, @leonheess. Many of us feel that the site we chose to dedicate years of our life to is crumbling before our eyes. Rearranging deck chairs on the Titanic is not exactly the most pressing order of business. Several moderators are on strike; others of us have lost the will to carry out extensive retags.  Many of these retags require community involvement, which means a [[meta-tag:featured]] post, and there's been a lot more pressing things in need of featuring as of late.

Comment: That does make sense. Thanks for the honest answer and the good metaphor. I'd say I have been somewhat following along with the events but am not deeply enough involved to assess the true state of this site. The community stands behind you guys so if we can help in any way or form: Tell us!

Comment: @leonheess - Maybe if the company understood the difference influential community members made we wouldn't be in this mess. Average users surely don't grasp the influence that users like Shog9 had, but over time it will become more and more obvious what is missing. Honestly, people are lucky that any of us even post on meta anymore. This place would fall apart at the seems without the constant guidance meta provides.